# Can dnsmasq use stale record in cache if cache expires and upstream fail?

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq

If all upstream dns server fail, can dnsmasq uses the local stale cache?

Or if not, is there any dns cache server support this feature?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/817589/can-a-local-dns-cache-be-configured-to-use-stale-records-when-upstream-fails

It looks like ubound dns can do that